# How can I install python3 and pyqt5 on travis

Tags: installation, travis-ci, pyqt5

I'm try to use travis ci to pull request. And I use python3 and pyqt5.

So, I have to make install line in .travis.yml.

But I don't know how to make python3 and pyqt5 install line.

Please, show me how.

Comment: Have you read Travis' documentation? Look for how to installing dependencies. It's in there and well documented.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should work:

```
language: python
sudo: required
dist: trusty

python:
  - "2.7"
  - "3.4"

virtualenv:
  system_site_packages: true

install:
 - sudo apt-get update
 - sudo apt-get -y install python3-pyqt5
```

Comment: Works for just python2.7 if you change `python3-pyqt5` to `python-qt4` and remove `- "3.4"` from `python:`.

Comment: @EL_DON Note that Qt4 has been unmaintained (end-of-life) since 2015, and Python 2 will be in 2020. I'd really recommend upgrading to Python 3 and PyQt5 if possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can compile `PyQt5` and `SIP` yourself:

```
language: python
sudo: required

python:
  - 3.4

before_install:
  - sudo apt-add-repository ppa:beineri/opt-qt551 -y
  - sudo apt-get update
  - sudo apt-get install qt-latest
  - source /opt/qt55/bin/qt55-env.sh

install:
  - sudo mkdir -p /builds && sudo chmod a+rw /builds
  - sudo mkdir -p /downloads && sudo chmod a+rw /downloads
  - curl -L -o /downloads/sip.tar.gz http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/sip/sip-4.17/sip-4.17.tar.gz
  - curl -L -o /downloads/pyqt.tar.gz http://skylink.dl.sourceforge.net/project/pyqt/PyQt5/PyQt-5.5.1/PyQt-gpl-5.5.1.tar.gz
  - tar xzf /downloads/sip.tar.gz -C /builds --keep-newer-files
  - tar xzf /downloads/pyqt.tar.gz -C /builds --keep-newer-files
  - cd /builds/sip-4.17 && python configure.py && sudo make && sudo make install
  - cd /builds/PyQt-gpl-5.5.1 && python configure.py --confirm-license && sudo make && sudo make install
```